# Call to Task<> method inside LINQ and return data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-8, task-parallel-library

I have a problem where im calling a `Task<>` method inside a LINQ statement and trying to return the data(images) from the `Task<>` method. I can't get the `Task<>` method to return the data(images), I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'
>   to 'System.Uri'.

Here is the DownloadStringCompleted method with LINQ statement, where im calling the GetTest Task<> method:

```
private async void GetGamesListRequestCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
    var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

    var gameData = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Game").Select(x => new GetGamesList
    {
        ID = (int)x.Element("id"),
        GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
        ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
        Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform"),
        Front = GetTest((int)x.Element("id")), // THE METHOD WITH PROBLEM.
    })
    .ToList();

    foreach (var item in gameData)
    {
        GetGamesListItems.Add(item);
    }
}
}
```

The Task<> GetTest method where i get the problem when trying to return data(images):

```
public Task<string> GetTest(int id)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var gameData = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Images").Select(x => new GetArt
            {
                BoxArtFrontThumb = new Uri(GetBoxArtFront(x)),
            })
            .ToList();

            foreach (var item in gameData) GetArtItems.Add(item);
            foreach (var i in GetArtItems)
            {
                tcs.SetResult("http://thegamesdb.net/banners/" + i.BoxArtFrontThumb.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.SetException(e.Error);
        }
    };

    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetArt.php?id=" + id.ToString()));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The ObservableCollection where i store the images:
    private ObservableCollection _GetArtItems = new ObservableCollection();

```
public ObservableCollection<GetArt> GetArtItems
{
    get
    {
        return this._GetArtItems;
    }
}
```

Where i get the images from XML:

```
private static string GetBoxArtFront(XElement gameNode)
{
    return "http://thegamesdb.net/banners/" + (string)gameNode.Descendants("boxart")
        .FirstOrDefault(b => (string)b.Attribute("side") == "front");
}
```

Here is the class i use to store the data(images):

```
public class GetArt
{
    public Uri BoxArtFrontThumb { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my LongListSelector i would like to show the data(images) in:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="llsGameList" Background="#242424" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Tap="llsGameList_Tap" Margin="0,90,0,0">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu">
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem 
                            Name="addToFavorite"  
                            Header="Add to favorite" 
                            Click="addToFavorite_Click"/>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
        Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
        Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                                        <TextBlock Name="tblGameTitle" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" ManipulationStarted="tblGameTitle_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="tblGameTitle_ManipulationCompleted">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding GameTitle}"></Run>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Front}" Height="200" Width="200"></Image> // HERE IM BINDING TO MY FRONT PROPERTY TO SHOW THE IMAGES
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="YellowGreen" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" 
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}">
                                        <Run Text="Platform: "></Run>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Platform}"></Run>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="YellowGreen" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" 
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}">
                                        <Run Text="Release Date: "></Run>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}"></Run>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
```

This is my DataContext which gets gd.GetGamesListItems which contains the images i would like to show in LongListSelector:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        llsGameList.DataContext = gd.GetGamesListItems;
    }
```

I hope there is someone that can help me :). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a `Task<T>`, you need to spend a bit of time thinking about how you want to (asynchronously) wait for the result. Remember, a `Task<T>` represents a *future* result, not a *current* result.

One option is as per @Sriram's answer, which will (asynchronously) wait for the results one at a time, adding them to a list as they arrive. Another option is to do something like this:

```
var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var gameDataTasks = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Game").Select(
    async x => new GetGamesList
    {
      ID = (int)x.Element("id"),
      GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
      ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
      Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform"),
      Front = new Uri(await GetTestAsync((int)x.Element("id"))),
    }).ToList();
var gameData = await Task.WhenAll(gameDataTasks);
foreach (var item in gameData)
{
  GetGamesListItems.Add(item);
}
```

This will start all of the `GetTestAsync` calls for all the elements, and then (asynchronously) wait for them all to complete (and retrieve the results).

Other notes:

- I did rename your method to `GetTestAsync` to conform with the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).
- I find the code is cleaner if you use the newer `HttpClient`, which has built-in support for `await`.

Here's an example of using `HttpClient`:

```
public async Task<string> GetTestAsync(int id)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetArt.php?id=" + id);
  var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(result);
  var gameData = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Images").Select(x => new GetArt
  {
    BoxArtFrontThumb = new Uri(GetBoxArtFront(x)),
  }).ToList();
  foreach (var item in gameData) GetArtItems.Add(item);
  return "http://thegamesdb.net/banners/" + gameData.Single().BoxArtFrontThumb.ToString()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering :). I will try and see if this works and post back :).

Comment: i tryed the code but i get 2 error: in the GetTestAsync method i get this error: Not all code paths return a value, and in the call Front = await GetTestAsync((int)x.Element("id")) i get this error: Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Uri :(

Comment: Yes, your original code had some issues. I can't fix it without knowing a lot more about your code, but both of those errors should have straightforward solutions.

Comment: I edited my question, i hope this helps explain what im trying to do :)

Comment: Your `GetTest` is still wrong; you can only call `SetResult` once, and you *must* complete the task completion source. That said, I've edited my answer to get it to behave how I think you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work at first, but it was because when it returned the data in the GetTestAsync method it returned this also: `thegamesdb.net/banners`, but this was already assigned to the Uri in the GetBoxArtFront method :). Thanks it works fine now!.

Comment: Do you know why i sometimes get this error: `Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete`?

Comment: No, but [this blog post might help](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/09/26/silverlight-2-post-beta2-gotcha---layout-cycle-detected.aspx).

Comment: I been using this method for a while now and it works fine except that the images does not get downloaded in the correct order. For example the images load like this sometimes: 1 6 9 3 5, where i would like it to load the images like this order: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. I hope you understand what i mean. Also do you know if its possible to only download and show images in my LongListSelector which is visible on the phone, so i don't download and show images which is out of view?.

Comment: The code in my answer will download all the images simultaneously, but will always add them to `GetGamesListItems` in the appropriate order. To prevent downloading images that are out of view, you should use virtualization, and in that case you'd need a "loading..." image that is replaced with the downloaded image. Feel free to post another question if this isn't clear; it's hard to write code in the comments.

Comment: Is it possible that you can make a chat room on here and invite me, so i can explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

To fix it you can call `Task.Result` but then method will execute synchronously waiting for async operation.

You have to mark the calling method also async and wait for `GetTest` asynchronously.

```
var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

List<GetGamesList> gameData = new List<GetGamesList>();
foreach (var item  in feedXml.Root.Descendants("Game"))
{
    var gl = new GetGamesList();
    gl.ID = (int)x.Element("id");
    gl.GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle");
    gl.ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate");
    gl.Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform");
    gl.Front = new Uri(await GetTest((int)x.Element("id")));//Note the await keyword

    gameData.Add(gl);
}
foreach (var item in gameData)
{
    GetGamesListItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this. So do i need to change my Task<> GetTest method also?

Comment: Damn :(, i tested the code you posted, but i get a error on this line: `tcs.SetResult("http://thegamesdb.net/banners/" + i.BoxArtFrontThumb.ToString());` with this error message: An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed your `GetTest` implementation is wrong, you're calling `tcs.SetResult` over the loop. but only once is allowed as a single task can only once be completed.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing in loop setting `tcs.SetResult`. `Task<string>` means it is going to return a string in future, but you're setting `SetResult` multiple times. Did you intend to return multiple strings for a single task? If so you need `Task<string[]>` not `Task<string>`. I'll sleep for now, i hope my comment helps. If anything I'll take a look morning. :)

Comment: I edited my question, i hope this helps explain what im trying to do :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it to work with @Stephen Cleary answer, but you have been really helpful also :). I wish i could give a answer to you too, but im only allowed to give one. :(.

Comment: @Thunder No worries you can upvote it :) I should admit that stephen's answer is better than mine which is more scalable. He has explained the difference between both clearly. You **should** go with it..

Comment: Hey again :). Do you know why i sometimes get this error: `Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete`.

Comment: @Thunder That's another question, I'll suggest you to ask another question :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I think calling tasks like that is a good idea but...The problem is your not getting the result from the task.

You need to either:

```
Front = GetTest().Result
```

or

```
Front = await GetTest()
```